# Error in stored procedure query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am getting following error in stored procedure as:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `comm_pay_intro`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `comm_pay_intro`(IN `id` VARCHAR(20),IN 
`comm_type` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER;
 DECLARE userid varchar(20);
 DECLARE rateid int(10);
 DECLARE levels int(1);
 DECLARE idx INTEGER;
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR (SELECT `id` , `user_id`
 FROM `temp_table` order by `id`);
OPEN curs1;
FETCH curs1 INTO idx,userid;
Select `level_id` into rateid , `levels` into levels FROM `user_levels`
 INNER JOIN `commission_type` ON `type_id`=`Commission_Type` WHERE 
`Commission_Type`=comm_type and `levels`=idx
order by `levels`;
   insert into user_commission(rate_id, user_id) 
VALUES(rateid,userid); 
CLOSE curs1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'into levels FROM `user_levels`
>   INNER JOIN `commission_type` ON `type_id`=`Comm' at line 13

Comment: Perhaps you can do the entire procedure with a single `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
 Select `level_id`,`levels` into rateid  levels FROM `user_levels`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change that `SELECT .. INTO` statement like below. Also, your variable name `levels` is same as column name; which may cause issue. Refrain from naming your variable like that.

```
Select `level_id`, `levels` into rateid , levels FROM `user_levels`
```

See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) for more information on same.